# VSCode Debugger for React Native with Webpack

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vscode-debugger

Does anyone know how to attach to a React Native app with vscode's debugger when using webpack?

I am using webpack because I am using RE:Pack which allows me to support micro frontends via module federation.

I run my app like this:

Run this in one terminal
`react-native webpack-start --host 127.0.0.1 --webpackConfig ./webpack.config.mjs`

Run this in another terminal:
`npm run native:android --appenv=local --mode=qadebug --appsuffix=qa`

I have downloaded the "React Native Tools" extension and attempted to debug with the default configuration for "attach to packager" but it seems it expects a /debugger-ui link that isn't there with webpack.